# "git svn rebase" no associated commit metadata

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I am mirroring a svn repository on my local computer and I decided to push it to a remote git server. The reason I needed to do so was so I could then add another repository as a submodule. However, now when I run the command:

```
    git svn rebase
```

I get:

```
    refs/remotes/origin/master: no associated commit metadata
```

I want to be able to update my local mirror from the svn repo and then push it to the remote git repository so that other people can clone that as a git repository.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to do that from a detached HEAD?

Comment: Please additionally post the output of `git config -l`

Answer (score 0):

A [git svn rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) (which fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and rebases the current -- uncommitted to SVN -- work against it) would fail if one of those commits rebased are pure git.

git 2.10 (Q3 2016) would still allow that rebase.
See [commit 2af7da9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2af7da9f8fb68337030630d88c19db512189babc) (02 Jul 2016) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
Suggested-by: [Jacob Godserv (`javaJake`)](https://github.com/javaJake).
See [commit 19e9542](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19e9542fa29ec3027a5169ac5d1fc740405dc234) (03 Jul 2016) by [Christopher Layne (`clayne`)](https://github.com/clayne).
Suggested-by: [Jacob Godserv (`javaJake`)](https://github.com/javaJake).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3f93370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f933701dc1b6249b050bbc96586929c3ffb6977), 11 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `git-svn`: warn instead of dying when commit data is missing
>
> It is possible to have refs globbed by `git-svn` which stores data purely in git; gently skip those instead of dying and assuming user error.
>
> ref: [mid.gmane.org thread](http://mid.gmane.org/CALi1mtdtNF_GtzyPTbfb7N51wwxsFY7zm8hsgwxr3tHcZZboyg@mail.gmail.com)